# SciKit-Learn Text Classification from ODBC

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, pyodbc, text-classification

I'm trying to adapt [this example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/document_classification_20newsgroups.html) to some social media data I have in a SQL server database.

I've intentionally forced both the training and test sets to only have social media posts that contain the word 'bunches'. Therefore I would expect an extremely high f-score for this word when I run it through all the algorithms. Instead I'm getting f-scores of around 2-4%. I have a feeling that I'm not feeding the data to the algorithms correctly.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import numpy as np
from time import time
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
import pyodbc
import pprint

#local windows connection
train = []
db = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};SERVER=SERVER_IP;DATABASE=DB_NAME;Trusted_Connection=Yes;')
cursor = db.cursor()
training_query = "SELECT top 2 percent postTitle FROM dbo.All_CH_Posts where monitorID ='1168136050' and postTitle like '%bunches%' ORDER BY NEWID()"
trainquery = cursor.execute(training_query)
traindata = cursor.fetchall()
for row in traindata:
    train.extend(row)

test = []
test_query = "SELECT top 1 percent postTitle FROM dbo.All_CH_Posts where monitorID ='1168136050' and postTitle like '%bunches%' ORDER BY NEWID()"
testquery = cursor.execute(test_query)
testdata = cursor.fetchall()
for row in testdata:
    test.extend(row)
print('traindata')
pp.pprint(traindata)
print('testdata')
pp.pprint(testdata)
print('data loaded')

# split a training set and a test set
y_train = train
y_test =test


print("Extracting features from the training dataset using a sparse vectorizer")
t0 = time()
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(decode_error='ignore',sublinear_tf=True,
                             stop_words='english', lowercase=True, min_df=20)
X_train = vectorizer.fit_transform(train)
duration = time() - t0

print("Extracting features from the test dataset using the same vectorizer")
t0 = time()
X_test = vectorizer.transform(test)
duration = time() - t0
print("n_samples: %d, n_features: %d" % X_test.shape)

feature_names = np.asarray(vectorizer.get_feature_names())
print(feature_names)
```

I intentionally set the min_df high to get a look at what words are in my sparse matrix:

```
n_samples: 237, n_features: 26
['almonds' 'amp' 'best' 'bowl' 'box' 'bunches' 'cereal' 'cheerios' 'crunch'
 'day' 'don' 'eat' 'eating' 'good' 'gt' 'honey' 'http' 'just' 'like' 'lol'
 'love' 'miss' 'morning' 'oats' 'rt' 'want']
```

So what am I doing wrong? Or am I thinking about this problem the wrong way/have a misconception of text classification?

[Here is my training set.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByAFICf5wlFqX00tMWpTem9oalE/view?usp=sharing)

[Here is my test set.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByAFICf5wlFqOWp4YWFpc3RBN28/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: So what are your labels? In the code you set ``y_train = train`` which looks like you are using the text as labels, which I find quite confusing. Which f-scores are you computing? Actually, if all texts have a common feature, the feature is non-informative and should have an f-score of zero (iirc).

Comment: Adding to @AndreasMueller comment , there is **Load some categories from the training set** section in the example code which means you need to specify the categories/labels for classification. Can you check the value of `data_train.target_names`? This should be list of classes you are trying to classify.

Comment: @Guru Ok I think I understand. If I were to add labels/categories they would be the monitorID's. I'm unclear how I keep the label connected to the data that goes through the vectorizor if my data comes from "select monitorID, postTitle from Table" since it will be a list of tuples and will crash the vectorizor.

Comment: You should not pass the labels to the vectorizer (well you can as y but it won't do anything). The labels are what is called y all over scikit-learn.

Comment: @AndreasMueller thanks. I'm having trouble with understanding how I would organize my data so it knows that certain labels are attached to certain posts in my training set. It seems like they are almost completely separate.

Comment: Then I am confused about what the task is you are trying to solve. You are talking about f-scores, so I assumed you want to do text classification. Is that not what you want to do?

Comment: Yes I do want to do text classification. It looks like you guys are right and my problem is lack of labels. So I guess the root of the problem is solved. I'm going to try a few things and will close the question.

Comment: Ok thanks guys. I have this solved. I didn't know that the labels are so loosely connected. Its literally a list of labels for each row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @AndreasMueller and @Guru. The problem was in my labels.

The solution is to create labels for each row.

```
training_query = "SELECT top 2 percent monitorID, postTitle FROM dbo.All_CH_Posts where monitorID in ('1168136050','469407080') and postTitle <>'' ORDER BY NEWID()"
trainquery = cursor.execute(training_query)
traindata = cursor.fetchall()
for row in traindata:
   train_data.append(row.postTitle)
   train_target.append(row.monitorID)

test_data = []
test_target = []
test_query = "SELECT top 2 percent monitorID, postTitle FROM dbo.All_CH_Posts where monitorID in ('1168136050','469407080') and postTitle <>'' ORDER BY NEWID()"
testquery = cursor.execute(test_query)
testdata = cursor.fetchall()
for row in testdata:
   test_data.append(row.postTitle)
   test_target.append(row.monitorID)

print("data loaded")


#assigning labels
train_le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
y_train = train_le.fit_transform(train_target)

test_le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
y_test = test_le.fit_transform(test_target)
```